# failed rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

When i typed: **sudo rake db:migrate**

I got:

```
rake aborted !    

/home/trace/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error,   unexpected ':', expecting $end...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_trace_session'
```

Note that my version of ruby is:

```
 ruby -v: 1.9.2p312
```

And that in my **bashrc** i have:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-final@rails310.
```

session_store.rb:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Trace::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_trace_session'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your `session_store.rb` file?

Comment: @Dupont Please edit your question to contain the new code. Don't post updated code in comments.

Comment: What if you try move your `rvm use 1.9.2-final@rails310` into `.rvmrc` (and try to remove dot at the end)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `sudo`... this is causing the system's Ruby (probably 1.8.7) to be used instead of your rvm Ruby. Just get rid of the sudo and run this:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenver rvm in used, sudo is skipped unless we need to install system libraries if the gem installation fails which installed in system. All the local gems are used from the gemset or from the global if no gemset is specified.Just have look over a tutorial on web to make things easier in rvm. solution suggested by dylan makes things clear.